# How to use the @ManyToMany with two lists on the same table

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many

I have a situation where an entity could use another entity, and it could be used by another, so i have defined a ManyToMany relation that reference the same entity, so i could have listUse and listUsedBy, and both are persisted in the same table entity_usage :

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "entity_usage",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "id_use", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "id_used_by", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private List<Entity> listUse;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "entity_usage",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "id_use_by", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "id_use", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private List<Entity> listUsedBy;
```

**Exemple** : Entity **A** could use Entity **B** and **C**, so Entity **B** and **C** are used by **A**. 
Now my problem is when i add B and C to listUse, they are persisted in entity_usage, but when try to display listUsedBy i have to redeploy my project, otherwise listUsedBy remains empty, is there a way to refresh listUsedBy when persist my entity without having to redeploy my project.

Comment: So, you want a bidirectional ManyToMany association. Here's the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the general approach:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity
{
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "entity_usage",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "using_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "used_by_id"))
    private Set<SomeEntity> using = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "using")
    private Set<SomeEntity> usedBy = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public void addUsing(SomeEntity entity)
    {
        this.using.add(entity);
        entity.usedBy.add(this);
    }

    public void addUsedBy(SomeEntity entity)
    {
        this.usedBy.add(entity);
        entity.using.add(this);
    }
}
```

and it's used:

```
public void someMethod(long parentEntityId, long childEntityId)
{
    EntityManager em = getSomeEntityManager();

    SomeEntity parentEntity = em.find(SomeEntity.class, parentEntityId);
    SomeEntity childEntity = em.find(SomeEntity.class, childEntityId);

    parentEntity.addUsing(childEntity);
}
```

typically this is a transactional EJB method.
Note that there's no need to `em.merge` anything, since entities are already *managed* by `em.find`.
Anyway, whichever method you'll use to manage your entities (query, find, persist, merge), remember that's **important** to call `addUsing`/`addUsedBy` **only when both entities are managed**.

This is one of the main incoherences that ORM logic cannot handle by its own: **you have to inform both entities (parent and child) of their relation**.
 It's not sufficient to set the relation only on one side - if you only say that A is parent of B, B still doesn't know who is its parent.

However, there exists alternative approaches, like setting only the owning side of the relation (`parent.getChildren().add(child)`), flush, and refresh the child.

Nevertheless (as I experienced very well on my skin) the alternatives are very hard to handle in real world complex applications.

As a side note, I'd use `Set` instead of `List` for the relation, unless you need some kind of insertion-order.

Comment: as you suggested i've added a mappedBy, but it works only on one side (using), when i add an object to usedBy, nothing is persisted in the table entity_usage

Comment: It's not just the mapping, it's the way it's used. The rest of the answer covers the general concept behind. If you post **how** you *link* the two entities - the EJB/JPA/transaction code - I can be more precise.

Comment: i read that there's two sides in manytomany relation, the owner side (using) and the inverse side (usedBy) which has the mappedby attribute, and the modification is only possible from the owner side, if there is a solution to this i will post another question

Comment: That's exactly true, but **the issue is not in the mapping!!**. The issue is **how** you use that mapping. I bet you're linking entities **outside** transaction or **detached** entities inside transaction. Neither double-owning side can save you from detached entities...